# In bridge which bids need alerting?

Tags: bridge, bidding

When playing bridge which bids need to be pointed out/alerted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you must alert when your bid does not conform to the expectations of the people at the event/table you are playing at.

Various organizations and clubs have more specific bids and conditions that you must alert on.  Some have bids that never require alerts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "alert" when you are bidding a special convention that your opponents would reasonably be expected not to know.

One example is my "one and a half" bids using a forcing one club or one diamond.

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3600/can-there-be-a-bid-of-one-and-a-half-in-bridge